# Using Matplotlib

Tags: deep-learning, numpy, plotting, matplotlib, ipython

I am new to data science. I use Anaconda on windows 7.
I plotted a sine curve by doing the following on iPython:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
```

And I got this:

[image]

But when I got ready to name the axes, the curve disappeared. I wrote this code:

```
plt.xlabel("Time")
```

And I got this:

[image]

I also wrote this:

```
plt.ylabel("Speed")
```

And got this:

[image]

The lecture video I use as a guide does not display images until the tutor enters the code "plt.show()". That gives me the impression that iPython adds all the information together behind the scene and displays the final result on request. But as you can see, my iPython displays the image without the "plt.show()" code and does not add previous instructions.

So, what should I do? (i.e. how can I plot a curve with labelled axes?)

Comment: You already have an answer at your first posting of the question.  (Please see my comment on the answer there: qtConsole has different default behavior than jupyter notebook or lab w.r.t. multi-line cells.)

Comment: Thanks for your response @Ben Reiniger. However, I am posting this question again because I am not sure I understand the answer you gave in the previous post. Are you saying I should try my hands on jupyter notebook or change the settings of qtConsole?

Comment: Then you should clarify at the other question, rather than asking again here.  You could use jupyter notebook, but you can continue using qtConsole as well.  In the latter case, after entering plt.plot(x,y), press Shift+Enter.  You will be given a new line instead of executing that line yet.  Then enter plt.xlabel("Time"), again shift+enter, then plt.ylabel("Speed"), again shift+enter, then plt.show(), now finally enter.  qtConsole will now run all these lines and should output just the one plot with all those bits.